# Change permissions for named volumes in Docker

Tags: docker

I have Docker container with named volume running on non-root user started with the following command:

```
docker run -v backup:/backup someimage
```

In the image, there's a backup script which is trying to save files in `/backup` directory but it fails. Mounted `backup` volume in `/backup` dir belongs to root user.

How to change permissions for `/backup` directory?

**-----EDIT1:**

mcve below:

Run docker container with Gerrit:

```
docker run -v backupgerrit:/backup --name gerrit gerritcodereview/gerrit
```

Now on other terminal window try to save something in `/backup` dir:

```
docker exec gerrit touch /backup/testfile
```

You will get:

```
touch: cannot touch '/backup/testfile': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Named volumes are initialized when first created to the contents of the image at the mount location. That initialization includes the owner and permissions. If `/backup` does not exist in your image, then an empty directory will be created and owned by root. You can:

**Option 1**: Create the directory in your Dockerfile with the appropriate ownership and permissions:

```
FROM your-image
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /backup \
 && chown -R your-user /backup
USER your-user
```

Note, this only works when the backup named volume does not already exist or is empty. And it needs to be a named volume, not a host volume.

**Option 2**: Initialize the named volume, including some content inside the volume (an empty file would work) using another temporary container:

```
docker run --rm -v backupgerrit:/backup busybox \
  /bin/sh -c 'touch /backup/.initialized && chown -R 1000:1000 /backup'
```

**Option 3**: Adjust the permissions after the volume is mounted, requiring root inside your container:

```
docker exec -u 0:0 your-container chown -R your-user /backup
```

Comment: I tested the first solution and it doesn't work. I created `/backup` dir in Dockerfile, changed ownership to `id=1000` but after containter start it is still root ownership. How to initialize named volume with empty file? You mean doing it before starting container?
For now I'm using third solution. Backup script is triggered by `docker exec -u root...` command.

Comment: @qkiz please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, something like a volume defined inside your Dockerfile could break things. Or trying to initialize a volume that already exists.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Your example was not minimal (over 500MB download), complete (mentioned a Dockerfile that was not included), or reproducible (pulling the requested image showed that `/backup` was not included in the image). Please review the mcve link.

Comment: It is minimal in configuration. Dockerfile is not needed because you can use image from Docker Hub. `backup` dir isn't needed in image. It will be created by Docker at container start if you use `docker run` command from example.

Comment: @QkiZ then you never attempted the first solution, so I'm not sure how you can say it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read first comment?

Comment: @QkiZ your first comment said you created a backup directory with the correct permissions in your image using the Dockerfile. Your third comment then said the opposite.

Comment: That's strange. When I was creating a directory in Dockerfile doesn't change anything because it's overridden by docker volume permissions. I have checked it and drop this way. It was some time ago. Now I back to this problem and your first solution works fine. Maybe I had some old Docker version that doesn't support changing permissions on named volumes...

Comment: @QkiZ from the comments above, when I checked the image you provided, the directory was never created in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution here. Docker on default settings keeps volumes data in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`. Basing on example from question files of `backupgerrit` named volume are keep in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/backupgerrit/_data`. Essential dir is `_data` and its permissions. In this example, Gerrit container uses a user with id 1000. The solution is to set ownership of this `_data` dir to `1000:1000`.

```
# chown 1000:1000 /var/lib/docker/volumes/backupgerrit/_data
# ls -ln /var/lib/docker/volumes/backupgerrit/
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Feb 25 12:19 _data/
```

And this is how it looks from container side:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND            CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                 NAMES
eaa816980be5   gerritcodereview/gerrit   "/entrypoint.sh"   31 minutes ago   Up 31 minutes   8080/tcp, 29418/tcp   gerrit
# docker exec gerrit id
uid=1000(gerrit) gid=1000(gerrit) groups=1000(gerrit)
# docker exec gerrit ls -l / | grep backup
drwxr-xr-x   2 gerrit gerrit 4096 Feb 25 11:19 backup
# docker exec gerrit touch /backup/testfile
# docker exec gerrit ls -l /backup
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 gerrit gerrit 0 Feb 25 11:19 testfile
```

Permissions of `_data` dir are persistent till removing volume with

```
# docker volume rm backupgerrit
```

Comment: This isn't portable since it relies on the underlying file structure of the internal docker directories, and also won't work if you alter any of the settings of the named volume, e.g. to use NFS. This would be better done with a temporary container that mounts the volume the same as docker mounts it in all other containers, abstracting away these docker internals.